# SQL:where column not equal return result else result equals blank value

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

So I am coming across an issue with a sql query (mssql) I have been working on that has multi-statement where clause, and one of the where statements may or may not return a value. If the where condition is not met how can I have it return an empty value and still return the rest of my results? I am also using multiple CTEs.

Here is my select clause:

```
select cte_devinfo.SerialNumber,
    cte_devinfo.DeviceName,
    cte_devinfo.DeviceID, 
    dev_CTE.concurrencies,
    (cte_slots.LocationIndex +1) as 'Total Media',
    cte_changer.SlotCount, cte_changer.TotalMountErrors, cte_changer.TotalMounts,
    cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber
from cte_devinfo, dev_CTE, cte_slots, cte_changer, cte_mismatch
```

Here is my where clause:

```
where cte_devinfo.DeviceID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID 
and cte_slots.LocationID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
and cte_changer.ChangerID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
and cte_mismatch.LocationID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
```

I want to add something like this to my where clause:

```
and cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber != cte_devinfo.SerialNumber
```

but this condition may never occur, and if it doesn't how can I ignore the condition and just return ' ' so the rest of the query will run?

Comment: You could add a case statement to the where clause:

Comment: cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber != cte_devinfo.SerialNumber means do you want all record which cte_devinfo.SerialNumber not exist in cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber is it right?

Comment: you can do it like this - `and cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber <> cte_devinfo.SerialNumber`

Comment: @PragneshKhalas Well in this case if the the statement is true and they do not match there is only a possibility of one other value, and I would only want this single non matching value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, rewrite your query using ANSI joins:

```
select cte_devinfo.SerialNumber,
    cte_devinfo.DeviceName,
    cte_devinfo.DeviceID, 
    dev_CTE.concurrencies,
    (cte_slots.LocationIndex +1) as 'Total Media',
    cte_changer.SlotCount, cte_changer.TotalMountErrors, cte_changer.TotalMounts,
    cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber
from cte_devinfo
inner join dev_CTE on cte_devinfo.DeviceID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
left outer join cte_slots on cte_slots.LocationID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
left outer join cte_changer on cte_changer.ChangerID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
left outer join cte_mismatch on cte_mismatch.LocationID = dev_CTE.DeviceParentID
```

I changed all joins except the first one to outer, to allow for missing records for slots, changers, and mismatches. `dev_CTE` remains required, though, because all tables are joined to the record from it.

Now you can add a `where` clause like this:

```
WHERE cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber IS NULL OR cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber != cte_devinfo.SerialNumber
```

This condition allows for `NULL` in `MismatchSerialNumber`, or even for missing `cte_mismatch` record.

Comment: what if `cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber` isnt null but the comparison `cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber != cte_devinfo.SerialNumber` returns flase this prevents the rest of the data/query from displaying because the where statement condition returns false

Comment: @JohnK In this case, the rows where `cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber != cte_devinfo.SerialNumber` evaluates to `FALSE` (i.e. rows where `cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber` is the same as `cte_devinfo.SerialNumber`) would be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks! to achieve the results I wanted I moved to the ANSI joins as mentioned, however instead of using the where statement you mentioned I added a where statement to cte_mismatch cte which will return a null value unless the comparison `cte_mismatch.MismatchSerialNumber != cte_devinfo.SerialNumber` is true.